# scraping a site and I get [] python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to python I'm trying to get data from this site and I get []

'''url = "https://br.betano.com/casino/games/aviator/3337/fun/"'''

```
api_id = 44444444
api_hash = '1231313131'
client = TelegramClient('teste12', api_id, api_hash)
#client.start()



chrome_driver_path = "./chromedriver.exe"
chrome_driver_options = Options()
#chrome_driver_options.add_argument("--headless")

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path = chrome_driver_path,
    options = chrome_driver_options
)
colors = None
def pegarsinais():
    blackk = 0
    redd = 0
    with webdriver as driver:

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

        driver.get(url)

        time.sleep(10)
        wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "app")))

        while True:    
            try:
               data = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/app-game/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]")][:1]
            except:
                data = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/app-game/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]")][:1]
            print(data)
            time.sleep(10)
```

I get [] when I print data, if anyone can help me where is the error
I already changed the xpath.

driver.find_elements I get empty list

driver.find_element I get error NoSuchElementException

driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'payouts-wrapper')
I get empty list again

Comment: Maybe the element you're trying to access by XPath isn't loaded on web page yet.. you can use inbuilt methods of selenium to wait until specific element becomes visible.

Comment: it finds the element but it does not return the value that is on the screen, but empty list []

Comment: have you tried to select the element by xpath you have written in web browser console and then getting it's text. Just to make sure if it works same or not on browser